# Google Maps API crashes on emulator API 23?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I created a new project with a Google Maps activity. When I try to run it on an emulator running API 23(w/Google Play APIs), it crashes with the following log:

```
02-03 09:59:18.475 2566-2566/com.mycompany.mapsdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.mycompany.mapsdemo, PID: 2566
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.mapsdemo/com.mycompany.mapsdemo.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                                                      at com.mycompany.mapsdemo.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:21)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                                      at com.mycompany.mapsdemo.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:21) 
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.ao.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
                                                                                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.
```

But when I run it on emulators API 22 and 21, it works fine. Why is this so? Is there a compatibility issue with the Maps API and emulator API 23 at the moment?

Also does this mean that the my Maps project will also crash if I try to run it on a physical device running API 23? I don't have access to a physical device running Marshmallow so I can't test for myself unfortunately. I do like to point out that my SDK tools are updated to the latest version. Anyone else experience this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main cause of the error you are experiencing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
```

For API 23, you need to insert an SD card in order for your code to run. See [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) for further details of the error.

Comment: Ah I see.. Yes, I can confirm it is indeed related to the SD card. As a temporary fix, I recreated and reconfigured my AVD just like what the project manager suggested in the link you shared. Now it works, but I'll keep an eye on the link you shared for updates on when the fix will be released. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 Map  map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
```

Instead of

```
           Map    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```